# How to disable bold fonts by overriding set-face-attribute in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs-faces

The idea is to redefine `set-face-attribute` so that it sets face attributes normally except for the `:weight` attribute, which shall always be set to `normal` (the default value, I think). With this I hope to disable bold fonts in Emacs once and for all.

I got this:

```
(fset 'original-set-face-attribute (symbol-function 'set-face-attribute))

(defun set-face-attribute (face frame &rest args)
  (progn
    (original-set-face-attribute face frame args)))
```

So far, it doesn't work. If I do `(make-face-bold 'default)` I get `Wrong type argument: symbolp, (:weight bold)`.  I think what I have
to do is remove elements that contain `:weight` from the list of arguments
`args`.

Comment: (1) You can use `defalias` instead of `fset`.  (2) Because `ARGS` is a `&rest` parameter, you need to use`apply`: `(apply #'original-set-face-attributes face frame args)`.

Comment: Personally, although I too hate the effect of `bold` on faces (on MS Windows, at least), I prefer to simply redefine the individual faces. For one thing, there is usually something else I want to change about them, if they use `bold`.

Comment: @Drew But there are hundreds of faces...

Comment: You're right. In my setup there are well over 300.  And I guess I don't bother to remove `bold` from all of them.  But then again, some of them I never see.  I guess I fix faces to be what I want on an as-needed (and as-seen) basis.

Comment: Where a bold font wants trumps another font, I set the other one to nil -- `:bold nil`.  I do the same for other attributes also.  Here is an example:  `(make-face 'linum-active) (set-face-attribute 'linum-active nil :foreground "black" :background "#eab700" :bold nil :italic nil :underline nil :box nil :overline nil :height 180)`

Answer (score 3):

Here's some code to start you off:

```
(defadvice set-face-attribute
    (before no-bold (face frame &rest args) activate)
  (setq args
        (mapcar (lambda(x) (if (eq x 'bold) 'normal x))
                args)))
```

I've seen this work for most of the cases, except for `basic-faces` that
don't call `set-face-attribute`, for instance the `error` face.

Comment: The attributes of the standard faces can be set via X resources, it's the non-standard ones that trouble me.

Answer (score 3):

Following Aaron's suggestion, here's another solution using
`face-remap-add-relative`.

```
(defun remap-faces-default-attributes ()
  (let ((family (face-attribute 'default :family))
        (height (face-attribute 'default :height)))
    (mapcar (lambda (face)
              (face-remap-add-relative
               face :family family :weight 'normal :height height))
          (face-list))))

(when (display-graphic-p)
  (add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook 'remap-faces-default-attributes)
  (add-hook 'change-major-mode-after-body-hook 'remap-faces-default-attributes))
```

This one gets rid of bold fonts everywhere and also of variable-width fonts
and sets all faces to the same height. Basically it's like running Emacs in a terminal window except with more colours.

Comment: If you catch the return value of FACE-REMAP-ADD-RELATIVE, e.g. in a hashtable keyed by `face`, then you can later pass it to FACE-REMAP-REMOVE-RELATIVE to disable the remapping.

Answer (score 0):

Alright! I improved on abo-abo's solution and this is what I've come up
with:

```
(defadvice set-face-attribute
  (before ignore-attributes (face frame &rest args) activate)
  (setq args
        (apply 'nconc
               (mapcar (lambda (i)
                         (let ((attribute (nth i args))
                               (value (nth (1+ i) args)))
                           (if (not (memq attribute
                                          set-face-ignore-attributes))
                               (list attribute value))))
                       (number-sequence 0 (1- (length args)) 2)))))

(setq set-face-ignore-attributes '(:weight :height :box))
```

It disables `:height`, `:weight` and `:box` attributes (this is configurable
via the `set-face-ignore-attributes` variable) for most fonts.  For this to
work, it has to go at the very beginning of `init.el` before the font
attributes are set.

Comment: If you find you need to override faces once they're set, consider FACE-REMAP-ADD-RELATIVE and friends.